# Formatting table cells with data top, bottom and right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to present a list of information in a table cell, but I can't get the css right. I have read posts regarding sending divs to the bottom of a cell, and experimented with position relative parent -> position absolute children. I still can't crack it - can you help?

I've created a fiddle here (https://jsfiddle.net/ngm6uavo/10/) that presents a football fixture table with a single row (it will be multi-row). Each cell contains a team's fixture data, which may be home or away. If home: opposition, kick-off, pitch, ref. If away: opposition. Either will have a 'status' label (unconfirmed/confirmed), and optionally show a cup image if it is a cup game.

The fixture data I want to render on individual subsequent lines starting at the top of cell, whether home or away. The data for any one line may wrap with long text e.g. "Referee: Somebody With A Really Long Name" The 'status' label I want to sit at the bottom and each one from each cell should align bottom with each other. Both fixture data and status label left aligned. The cup image I want to render bottom right if shown (same baseline as the status label).

I have tried different methods as you can see from the fiddle; divs, spans and one cell with `<br>`s (not good). I thought that using divs would work best but I'm very open to suggestions that may solve this more easily (e.g. table / form within cell).

You can see that I have included bootstrap stylesheet to prettify the table, I don't think it is interfering.

css:

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

table, thead, tbody, tr, td{
        position: relative;
    }

    .td-fixture{
        background-color: #eaeded;
        border: 1px solid #ccd1d1 ;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .date-span{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .date-hdr {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size:20px;
        vertical-align:middle !important;
        color: #21618C;
        background-color: #d6eaf8;
        border-top: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
        border-left: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
    }

    .fixture-hdr {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size:20px;
        color: #21618C;
        background-color: #d6eaf8;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        border-top: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
        border-left: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
        border-right: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
        border-bottom: none !important;
    }

    .fixture-subhdr {
        text-align: center;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #21618C;
        background-color: #d6eaf8;
        padding-top: 2px;
        border-top: none !important;
        border-left: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
        border-right: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #ccd1d1  !important;
    }

    .textBoxStyle{
        text-align:left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border:1px outset #9a9;
        background: #e5e8e8;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }

    .fixtureLabel{
        font-weight:bold;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .fixtureUnconfirmed{
        color: #ff0000;
    }

    .fixtureConfirmed{
        color: #269816 ;
    }

    .fx-input{
        background: #fffdbf;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    td.div-container{
        position:absolute;
        top: 0;
    }

    td.div-status{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    td.div-cup{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right:0;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<h2>Saturday Teams</h2>
  <table id="tbl-sat-1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th rowspan="2" class="date-hdr">Date</th>
        <th class="fixture-hdr" id="29">U7 Lions</th>
        <th class="fixture-hdr" id="33">U9 Tigers</th>
        <th class="fixture-hdr" id="41">U10 Bears</th>
        <th class="fixture-hdr" id="38">U10 Sharks</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="fixture-subhdr">EBFA A</th>
        <th class="fixture-subhdr">EBFA A</th>
        <th class="fixture-subhdr">EBFA C</th>
        <th class="fixture-subhdr">EBFA A</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="tr-fixtures">
      <td class="td-fixture date-span">
        <span>2017-09-16</span>
      </td>
      <td class="td-fixture">
        <div class="div-container">
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Reeves Rangers</span><br/>
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Kickoff: </span><span>10:00</span><br/>
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Pitch: </span><span>11as pitch 2</span><br/>
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Referee: </span><span>Appointed</span><br/>
            <div class="div-status">
                <span class="fixtureUnconfirmed textBoxStyle">Unconfirmed</span>
            </div>
            <div class="div-cup">
                <img id='cup' src='http://nplyouthfootball.co.uk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/gold-cup.png' style='width:28px;height:35px;'/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td-fixture">
        <div class="div-container">
            <div><span class="fixtureLabel">Reeves Rangers</span><br/></div>
            <div><span class="fixtureLabel">Kickoff: </span><span>10:00</span></div>
            <div><span class="fixtureLabel">Pitch: </span><span>11as pitch 2</span></div>
            <div><span class="fixtureLabel">Referee: </span><span>Appointed</span></div>
            <div class="div-status">
                <span class="fixtureUnconfirmed textBoxStyle">Unconfirmed</span>
                <img id='cup' src='http://nplyouthfootball.co.uk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/gold-cup.png' style='width:28px;height:35px;'/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td-fixture">
        <div class="div-container">
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Reeves Rangers</span><br/>
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Kickoff: </span><span>10:00</span><br/>
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Pitch: </span><span>11as pitch 2</span><br/>
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Referee: </span><span>Appointed</span><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="div-status">
            <span class="fixtureUnconfirmed textBoxStyle">Unconfirmed</span>
            <img id='cup' src='http://nplyouthfootball.co.uk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/gold-cup.png' style='width:28px;height:35px;'/>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="td-fixture">
        <div class="div-container">
            <span class="fixtureLabel">Reeves Rangers</span><br/>
            <div class="div-status">
                <span class="fixtureUnconfirmed textBoxStyle">Unconfirmed</span>
                <img id='cup' src='http://nplyouthfootball.co.uk/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/images/gold-cup.png' style='width:28px;height:35px;'/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you forgot to include `<tbody>`

Secondly, if you want vertical-align to work, you should not include bootstrap

All in all I thought that you really need to improve your skills in css and html to make tables look the way you imagine. Here is the Pen with ready-made table:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QqGMXp?editors=1100

The list of improvements would be quite long, the most important things -
 positioning in blocks (as you have tried div-s) is not that complicated, try to keep your code dry as much as possible, because when your data grows, the code mass grows as well. Also, try to apply the "keep-dry-rule" to styles, when you set 3 borders the same way and 1 another, it's easier to set all the borders and exclude 1 from them (for example).

I'll leave you with advice of learning following materials:

https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss
https://www.udemy.com/html-and-css-for-beginners-crash-course-learn-fast-easy/

These simple courses cover basics, but they will surely improve your skills

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I have added `<tbody>` and removed the bootstrap css, but it has made no difference to the layout. I'm not using vertical-align in the css I am using `position:absolute;bottom:0;`. I tried using `vertical-align` in the 'absolute' divs but saw no difference?

Comment: Okay, i'll explain you one thing `td.div-status` and `td .div-status` are different things:

`td.div-status` - is style for `<td class="div-status">` or `<div class="td div-status">`
. Meanwhile 
`td .div-status` - is style for `<td><div class="div-status">` - for the div you want to style in your case, so if you really in a bad need of absolute positioning - try fixing all the css which are without spaces now first of all :)

Comment: OK thanks again. However when I change the css for the absolute divs to `td .div-status` etc the formatting gets worse - in that the cell contents spills over the parent cell. I also tried changing to `.div-status` because I don't believe the `td` is required. Perhaps you could check the fiddle if you had a moment?

Comment: @Will, sorry I was out of network, I'll make a separate sandbox for you

Comment: @Will, here goes the updated answer, mind that if you want the status + cup to be in 1 line, you can just set `float:left` to status and `float:right` to the cup block

Comment: thanks again for looking at my problem, and for creating a demo. Unfortunately it doesn't work as I expected: if I remove an entry in the `div-container` the status label & cup shift up and aren't aligned with other cells' status labels. This is the key part to my question: pin the fixture content to the top of the cell and the status label to the bottom, regardless of length of fixture content. This is why I thought absolute positioning within a relative parent was the 'correct' way. I will have a look at those links, especially the code academy: positioning with css. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Will, I will kindly ask you to check the Pen once again, if the table-structure is not what you need - look into flexbox, it can also solve the issue. I hope you'll figure out how to hide the unneeded space between cells and how to hide borders ;)